# Find the probability exactly one bulb lasts longer than $3500$ hrs.

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

> Robert buys one energy-saving bulb and one halogen bulb.
>   1. The probability that the energy-saving bulb lasts longer than $3500$ hrs is $\frac{9}{10}$.
>   2. The probability that the halogen bulb lasts longer than $3500$ hrs is $\frac{3}{5}$. What is the probability that exactly one of them lasts longer than $3500$ hrs?

My Attempt:

Let $A$ be the event of energy saving bulb lasting longer than $3500$ hrs, then $P(A)=\frac9{10}$ and $P(\overline{A})=\frac1{10}$.

Let $B$, be the event of halogen bulb lasting longer than $3500$ hrs, then $P(B)=\frac{3}{5}$ and $P(\overline{B})=\frac{2}{5}$.

$P($exactly one lasts longer than $3500$ hrs$)$=$P((A\cap\overline{B})\cup(\overline{A}\cap B)$.

Using this, I got the answer $\frac{21}{50}$. But I do not know if my answer is correct or not.
Can you please help me verify my solution? Thank you.

Comment: $P(A)+P(B)-1 = \frac{5}{10}$ seems to say that there's a more than 50% chance that they both last more than 3500 hrs. misinterpreted at first.

Comment: We want to calculate the probability of exactly one lasting more than 3500 hrs.

Comment: yeah but it shows at least it has to be lower than 50%, because 50% of the time both last more than that.

Comment: Can you please post your solution as answer.

Comment: it's not a solution it's a stepping stone to double check it makes sense.

Comment: So, does my answer make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct answer.

The probability of exactly one is the sum of (A and Not B) and (Not A and B).

Comment: Thank you ,Saketh.